# Websocket(Jetty) : How to handle the binary data on server side which is coming in chunks

Tags: java, websocket, server, jetty, java-websocket

I need to setup a websocket server which can receive audio data sent by the client. I am using Jetty for this.

My handler code :

```
{
    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
    }

    @OnWebSocketError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
    }

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session session) {

    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessage(bytes [] b) {
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void inputStream(InputStream is) {
    }
}
```

Since the audio file is quite large, the client is sending those in chunks.
Now for every chunk, the `onMessage(bytes [] b) {}` method is getting invoked.

On the server side, I need to add these chunks and process the audio. How can I do that?

Also what is the difference between `onMessage(bytes [] b) {}` and `onMessage(InputStream is) {}` methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the `onMessage` [javadoc](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.4/javax/websocket/OnMessage.html),
both `onMessage(byte[] b)` and `onMessage(InputStream is)` will receive the *whole* message:

> if the method is handling binary messages:
>
> - byte[] or ByteBuffer to receive the **whole** message
> - InputStream to receive the **whole** message as a blocking stream

So, if you use one of these methods, Jetty will automatically reassemble the chunks and deliver the whole message to your method (as a `byte[]` array or an `InputStream`).

The maximum size of the binary message, you can receive this way, is set with the  [setMaxBinaryMessageSize](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/WebSocketPolicy.html#setMaxBinaryMessageSize-int-)

Also note, that you may only have one of these methods defined at your Handler class at once:

> Each websocket endpoint may only have **one** message handling method for each of the native websocket message formats: text, binary and pong.

If you want to process the data as it goes, you should use the following method signature instead:

```
@OnMessage
public void processUpload(byte[] b, boolean last, Session session) {
    // process partial data here, which check on last to see if these is more on the way
}
```

and manually buffer your data (in memory or disk file e.t.c.)

The client, in turn, should use one of [sendPartialBytes](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/RemoteEndpoint.html#sendPartialBytes-java.nio.ByteBuffer-boolean-) methods, to send the data chunk by chunk.

---

If what you observe is the "whole message" method (i.e. `onMessage(byte[] b`) being invoked for an each data chunk, as send by the client, this indicates that the client is not utilizing the protocol [capabilities](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.4) to send chunked messages, and does instead split the input data and then sends its parts as *independent* WS messages, effectively creating it's own application level protocol for transmitting the data in chunks.

In this case, you must either update the client (if that is an option),
to make it use a regular WS protocol capabilities, or implement the same "application level protocol" the client is using.

Below is a super-simple endpoint example, which will buffer the input data
until the WS socket is closed (this implies that client will close the connection once it has sent all the chunks).

```
@ServerEndpoint("/data")
public static class Handler {

    private ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(byte[] message) throws IOException {
        buffer.write(message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(
            buffer.toByteArray().length
        );
    }

}
```

This implementation also implies that a default *ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator* is used, so that there is exactly one Endpoint instance per connection (as documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Endpoint.html)).

A more complex implementation might want to reuse the socket to send multiple files, and specify a mechanism to denote the start and end of each transmission (e.g. with a specially formatted message), but it all depends on how your client is implemented.

Comment: >>Jetty will automatically reassemble the chunks and deliver the whole message to your method (as a byte[] array or an InputStream).  Jetty is not reassembling. For each chunks my byte method is getting called.

Comment: @shantanu - Jetty does reassemble the fragmented message correctly when data is sent in a spec-compatible way. Most probably your client simply sends each chunk as an independent WS message instead (please see my update on this).